# mongoose .save() doesn't work on a specific collection

Tags: node.js, mongoose

so I'm trying to create a party with creator field with id of a user, and at the same time adding a party id to users parties using mongoose sessions. Here's the code of a request:

```
const createParty = async (req, res, next) => {
    const {title, description, address, creator} = req.body;
    const createdParty = new Party({
        title,
        description,
        image: 'https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/14/03/b3/4e/tlv.jpg',
        address,
        creator,
        savedBy: []
    });

    let user;
    try {
        user = await User.findById(creator);
    } catch (err) {
        let error = new HttpError('Fetching user failed', 500);
        return next(error);
    }

    if (!user) {
        return next(new HttpError('Could not find user for providen id', 404));
    }

    try {
        const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
        sess.startTransaction();
        await createdParty.save({ session: sess });
        user.parties.push(createdParty);
        console.log(user);
        await user.save({ session: sess });
        await sess.commitTransaction();
    } catch (err) {
        let error = new HttpError('Creating party failed', 500);
        return next(error);
    }
    
    res.status(201).json({party: createdParty});
};
```

And my user and parties schemas:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 6 },
    image: { type: String, required: true },
    parties: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Party' }],
    savedParties: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Party' }]
});

const partySchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    creator: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
    savedBy: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' }]
});
```

The problem is I can't save a user with new party id, only this line fails:
`await user.save({ session: sess });`. Tried to move this line to a separate try/catch, tried to add `user.markModified('parties');` didn't help. Please help those who may know the solution.

**UPDATE ON THE PROBLEM**

So I did some testing and found out that if I delete everything from the database, and I'll create a user I will be able to add parties, and it'll work as it should. But if I'll create another user and afterward will try to add a party to one of the users it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

when you session it won't create the collection if it doesn't exist and you need to do it manually in the data